# Appearance of the text color is white in the real device though it has been mentioned black ( working fine in the emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator, textcolor

So, I was trying to create a customized wedding card in Android Studio. The code is given below. I noticed difference in **textColor**  while building it in the emulator and real device. **Though the color of this attribute has been defined as black but in the real device it appears as white**. Screenshots of the real device and emulator appearance have been mentioned in the link below:

1. [Appearance in the Real Device](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RcbfdiHh6yzPgWCld_P6IW_7OIrH8Exe/view?usp=sharing)
2. [Appearance in the Emulator](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17JpogU_fOkRlYfcDMK6f0bGHkuwZOnnf/view?usp=sharing)

**Android Studio Version: 4.1.1**

Any suggestions about how this issue can be solved in terms of real device?
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wedding_Card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wedding_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wedding_card"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/petals"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="716dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pink" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flower_top"
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/save_date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/floral_pattern"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"

        android:text="@string/save_the_day"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/flower_bou"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/_25_12_2020"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bride_groom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flower_bou"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/emma"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/flower_bou" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flower_bou"
        android:layout_width="81dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bride_groom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flower_bouquet"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bride_groom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bride_groom"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/dexter"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bride_groom" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bride_groom"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bride_groom"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/We_getting_married"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bride_groom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/we_are_getting_married"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/We_getting_married"
        android:text="@string/at_five_o_clock_in_the_evening"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cityLove"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/time"
        android:text="@string/city_of_love"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/avenue"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/cityLove"
        android:text="@string/flower_avenue"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/church"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/avenue"
        android:text="@string/st_rose_church"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dinner_dancing_to_follow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/church"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/dinner_and_dancing_to_follow"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What model is the "real device"? And which Android version?

Comment: Thanks for your time. I actually figured out the solution. Dark mode was on in my mobile phone that is why the appearance was different. I turned off the dark mode and it solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know :) So it seems like a good idea to test your app (and apps in general) in both modes. Since the users of your app may have dark mode turned on as device default. One other dimension besides different sizes, orientations and OS versions... I <3 Android ... :D

Comment: For me, in CSS, the color: white; was mentioned in @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) and I was not aware of it.